# How do I treat this "lamp" to find power dissipated?

Tags: power-dissipation

[image]

This is my circuit. I need to find the power dissipated by `Vlamp`. So the lamp turns on if the `Vlamp` is more than 2V. When the lamp is on it has an internal resistance of 10 Ohms, and when it is off it acts like an open circuit.

How would I find the power dissipated? I know how to do it for Voltage sources and Resistors, but not elements like these.

One more thing, I already figured out that:
`Battery has open circuit voltage of 4V`
`R1 = 5 Ohms`
`R2 = 5 Ohms`
`k = 0.2A/V`
`When lamp on and Vlamp = 2V, Rbat = 10 Ohms`

.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the power equations, P=I^2*R and P=V^2/R, you can use either one.

For the lamp, if its on, the equation would be \$P = V_{lamp}^2/2\$

You can analyze the circuit like normal to find V_lamp

Another way you could do this is if you find the current and the voltage through the lamp, then use the equation P=I*V